# Seaborn heat map with gaps

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I am using a [dataset from kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/orgesleka/used-cars-database) and trying to do some data analysis on that.

First I computed the price average per group of brand and vehicle type ([This is my average code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oohW.png)) and after that, I did the heat map from this average ([Heat map code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnWMD.png))([Heat map figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qYZG.png)). However, a noticed that in the dataset some brands do not have all vehicle types, for instance, alfa_romeo does not show "bus" type. This becomes a problem because this absence appears as a gap in Heat Map.

How can I overcome this situation, for example, putting zero value where there is a gap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the argument, `fill_value = 0` to your `df.pivot` in your `Heat map code`. This should replace `NULL` values with `0` and prevent gaps from showing up in your heat map.

EDIT: Error with my solution since `pandas.DataFrame.pivot` does not have an argument for `fill_value`. A much better alternative would be `pandas.pivot_table`, which is more or less equivalent to `pandas.pivot` but with more flexibility. See here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html

Here's how your line should be rewritten:

```
import pandas as pd
df2_pivot = pd.pivot_table(data = df2, 
                           index = 'brand', 
                           columns = 'vehicleType', 
                           values = 'avgPrice', 
                           fill_value = 0)
```

Alternatively, you can also run:

```
df2_pivot = df2.pivot(index = 'brand', 
                      columns = 'vehicleType', 
                      values = 'avgPrice').fillna(0)
```

Comment: @Elias Rodrigues, if this solution solved your problem could you please accept it? Thanks!